# jQuery multiple Select Dropbox not working

Tags: asp.net

Im using the multiple select dropdownlist referring the below link.

https://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/03/jquery-multiselect-dropdown-list-with-checkboxes.html

Its not working for me.i have a master page with update panel and im trying to add this dropdown on content page. Please help.

output im getting is
[image]

i need output like below

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Got a charming **multi select searchable dropdownlist** .
[image]

**Download and add the below jquery plugin** to your project

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Then add below

```
<link href="mdropdown/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="mdropdown/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="mdropdown/docsupport/prism.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
       function pageLoad(sender, args) {

           $(document).ready(function () {

               $(function () {
                   $(".chzn-select").chosen();
               });
           });
       }
   </script>
```

Here is the **control**

```
<select class="chzn-select u-full-width" id="ddlEmployee" multiple="true" runat="server" required ="required"  name="faculty" ></select>
```

**On code behind**

```
  'Bind dropdown as usual
        ddlEmployee.DataSource = dt
        ddlEmployee.DataTextField = "Name"
        ddlEmployee.DataValueField = "Username"
        ddlEmployee.DataBind()

'Set selected value in the dropdown

        Dim Items = Value.Split(",")
        For Each item In Items
        ddlEmployee.Items.FindByValue(item.ToString()).Selected= True
        Next
'To get selected items


        Dim empname As String
        empname = ""
        For Each item As ListItem In ddlEmployee.Items
          If item.Selected Then
           empname  += String.Format("{0},", item.Text.ToString())
          End If
        Next
        empname = empname .Remove(empname .Length - 1)
```